# Using NUnit to test HTTP status of a WebFaultException

Tags: unit-testing, exception, nunit

I want to write a unit test to ensure that I get a WebException with a 404 status code thrown from a particular method.

The WebException bit is easy:

```
[Test]
[ExpectedException(typeof(WebFaultException))]
public void CheckForWebFaultException()
{
  var myClass = new MyClass();
  myClass.MyMethod();
}
```

However this could be a 404, a 400, 401 or any other of the myriad of other http codes.

I could do a try/catch/Assert.True but this feels like a hack. Is there a way to Assert against a property of the thrown exception?

Something like

```
Assert.Throws(typeof(WebFaultException), myClass.MyMethod(), wfx => wfx.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was on the right lines, Assert.Throws actually returns the exception which was thrown.

```
[Test]
public void CheckForWebFaultException()
{
  var myClass = new MyClass();  
  var ex = Assert.Throws<WebFaultException>(() => myClass.MyMethod());
  Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex.StatusCode);    
}
```

Note that I've taken out the `[ExpectedException(typeof(WebFaultException))]` as the exception is now handled and the test will fail if this is left in.

`Assert.Throws` ensures that the exception was thrown by `myClass.MyMethod()` and the second assert checks the status code.